# Braces: [Brackets], (Parentheses) & {Curlies} in Ruby & Rails

Tags: ruby, jrubyonrails, parentheses, curly-braces, square-bracket

So the loose tolerance of Ruby to use braces *sometimes* and not REQUIRE them has led to alot of confusion for me as I'm trying to learn Rails and when/where to use each and why?

Sometimes parameters or values are passed as `(@user, @comment)` and other times they seem to be `[ :user => comment ]` and still others it's just: `:action => 'edit'`

I'm talking about the us of **[ ]** vs **( )** vs **{ }**

What ARE the rules? And are there any tricks you have to help you remember?

Comment: FYI, "{" and "}" are the only "Braces."  The common term for all of those is brackets.  When not specified the word "brackets" refers to square brackets.

Answer (score 23):

Parentheses `()` are for grouping logical or mathematical expressions and grouping arguments to a function call, e.g.:

```
a = 2 * (3 + 4)
b = (x==y) || (m==n)
Hash.new.send('[]=', :a, :b)
```

Curly Braces `{}` are used for hash literals and blocks, e.g.:

```
h = {1=>2, 2=>3}
h.each {|k,v| puts k+v}
```

Square Brackets `[]` are used for array literals, array indexing and slicing, and fetching from a hash, e.g.:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
two = arr[1]
three = h[2]
```

To confuse the matter, hash literals can also be used in-place as an argument to a method call without needing the curly braces or parentheses as long as it is the last argument (thanks samuil).  Additionally, hash literals can be used in-place in square brackets to create a single-item array containing the hash:

```
puts 1=>2, 3=>4 #=> 1234
[5=>6, 7=>8]    #=> [{5=>6, 7=>8}]
```

When in doubt, always use parentheses to group items and wrap your hashes in curly braces.

Comment: Note, that curly braces can be omitted when passing a hash to a function as an argument only if it is last one.